# Google Maps loading only after page refresh

Tags: javascript, html, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

For some reason my google maps is only loading, after I refresh the page. I already tried a some fixes, but they haven't worked for me.

I already added

```html
    $(document).ready(function() {
      initMap();
});

    $(document).bind("projectLoadComplete", initMap);
```

to my code, but it doesn't fix the problem.

Some guys also use `google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);` instead of `$(document).ready(function() {initMap();});` but then I get the error: "Google is not defined".

Here's the full HTML Code without css:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Marker</title>
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Raleway&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
  <script src="https://polyfill.io/v3/polyfill.min.js?features=default"></script>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript">
    function initMap() {

      window.onmessage = (event) => {
        if (event.data) {

          const map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map"), {
            center: new google.maps.LatLng(48.68933623258264, 11.05938929396435),
            zoom: 5,
            streetViewControl: false,
            fullscreenControl: true,
            zoomControl: true,
          });
          const input = document.getElementById("pac-input");
          const autocomplete = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(input);
          autocomplete.setComponentRestrictions({
            country: ["de", "ch", "at", "it", "lie"]
          });
          autocomplete.bindTo("bounds", map);

          var markerIcon = {
            url: "https://static.wixstatic.com/media/c4g8dl_c2fd4dfd9ce72ede7acb9e44~mv2.png",
            size: new google.maps.Size(22, 35),
            origin: new google.maps.Point(0, 0),
            scaledSize: new google.maps.Size(22, 35)
          };

          autocomplete.setFields(["place_id", "formatted_address", "geometry", "name"]);
          const infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();
          const infowindowContent = document.getElementById("infowindow-content");
          infowindow.setContent(infowindowContent);

          const marker = new google.maps.Marker({
            map: map,
            icon: markerIcon
          });
          marker.addListener("click", () => {
            infowindow.open(map, marker);
          });
          autocomplete.addListener("place_changed", () => {
            infowindow.close();
            const place = autocomplete.getPlace();

            if (!place.geometry || !place.geometry.location) {
              return;
            }

            if (place.geometry.viewport) {
              map.fitBounds(place.geometry.viewport);
            } else {
              map.setCenter(place.geometry.location);
              map.setZoom(17);
            }

            marker.setPlace({
              placeId: place.place_id,
              location: place.geometry.location,
            });
            marker.setVisible(true);
            infowindowContent.children.namedItem("place-name").textContent = place.name;
            infowindowContent.children.namedItem("place-address").textContent = place.formatted_address;
            infowindow.open(map, marker);

            window.parent.postMessage([place.name, place.formatted_address, place.geometry.location.lat(), place.geometry.location.lng()], "*");
          });
        }
      }
    }

    function ready() {
      window.parent.postMessage({
        "type": "ready"
      }, "*");
    }

    $(document).ready(function() {
      initMap();
    });
    $(document).bind("projectLoadComplete", initMap);
  </script>
</head>

<body onload="ready()">

  <div id="input">
    <input id="pac-input" class="controls" type="text" placeholder="adress">
  </div>

  <div id="map"></div>

  <div id="infowindow-content">
    <span id="place-name" class="title"></span><br />
    <span id="place-address"></span><br />
  </div>

  <script type="text/javascript" src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=MY_KEY&callback=initMap&libraries=places&v=weekly" async defer></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Edit: If I open the page with my Map in a new Tab, the map is loading. The error just occurs, if I open the page in the same tab.
Maybe my website doesn't fire the full code of my iFrame.

Comment: No need for any onload/ready listener. You already have `callback=initMap` in the script src. Mabye you should read the **[first page](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/overview)** of the docs?

Comment: Why are you using the `onmessage` event handler?  Is this on a `wix.com` website? (if so, that would be useful information to include in the question).  You mention an `<iframe>` in your latest edit.  What `<iframe>`?  I don't see on in the posted HTML.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed the issue. The problem was the `window.onmessage = (event) => {`.
I think the map couldn't load, because the callback runs before the map receives an onmessage event.

I used the code from another map I created, so I just deleted the onmessage part, because I only need to send some data to my website and not from my website to my html.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Marker</title>
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Raleway&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
  <script src="https://polyfill.io/v3/polyfill.min.js?features=default"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript">
    function initMap() {

      const map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map"), {
        center: new google.maps.LatLng(48.68933623258264, 11.05938929396435),
        zoom: 5,
        streetViewControl: false,
        fullscreenControl: true,
        zoomControl: true,
      });

      const input = document.getElementById("pac-input");
      const autocomplete = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(input);
      autocomplete.setComponentRestrictions({
        country: ["de", "ch", "at", "it", "lie"]
      });
      autocomplete.bindTo("bounds", map);

      var markerIcon = {
        url: "https://static.wixstatic.com/media/e6dc2fd4dfd9ce72ede7acb9e44~mv2.png",
        size: new google.maps.Size(22, 35),
        origin: new google.maps.Point(0, 0),
        scaledSize: new google.maps.Size(22, 35)
      };

      autocomplete.setFields(["place_id", "formatted_address", "geometry", "name"]);
      const infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();
      const infowindowContent = document.getElementById("infowindow-content");
      infowindow.setContent(infowindowContent);

      const marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        map: map,
        icon: markerIcon
      });
      marker.addListener("click", () => {
        infowindow.open(map, marker);
      });
      autocomplete.addListener("place_changed", () => {
        infowindow.close();
        const place = autocomplete.getPlace();

        if (!place.geometry || !place.geometry.location) {
          return;
        }

        if (place.geometry.viewport) {
          map.fitBounds(place.geometry.viewport);
        } else {
          map.setCenter(place.geometry.location);
          map.setZoom(17);
        }

        marker.setPlace({
          placeId: place.place_id,
          location: place.geometry.location,
        });
        marker.setVisible(true);
        infowindowContent.children.namedItem("place-name").textContent = place.name;
        infowindowContent.children.namedItem("place-address").textContent = place.formatted_address;
        infowindow.open(map, marker);

        window.parent.postMessage([place.name, place.formatted_address, place.geometry.location.lat(), place.geometry.location.lng()], "*");
      });
    }
  </script>
</head>

<body onload="initMap()">

  <div id="input">
    <input id="pac-input" class="controls" type="text" placeholder="add adress">
  </div>

  <div id="map"></div>

  <div id="infowindow-content">
    <span id="place-name" class="title"></span><br />
    <span id="place-address"></span><br />
  </div>

  <script type="text/javascript" src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=MY_KEY&callback=initMap&libraries=places&v=weekly" async defer></script>
</body>

</html>
```